# Divide array in multiples arrays based on height

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a lot of elements like p, span, h1, h2. I don't know how much because it is dynamic. I need to separate elements into a `div` with 1000px height. So, I need to create multiple pages from one array, based on height.

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  $('.page').append(items[i]);
}
```

Elements example: `items = [<ul class="ul1">..</ul>, <p class="p2">..</p>, <p class="p2">..</p>, <table>...</table>, <p class="p2">..</p>,<p class="p2">..</p>,<p class="p2">..</p>]`

`items` have all HTML elements and it is dynamical, can have 10 or 100 elements. The idea is to return page1, page2, page3... etc, with 1000px and the elements. For now, I have one page with all the content.

Comment: Can you share the items array with us? These are not enough informations.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly just do $('.page').innerHTML = items[i]; instead of append. Don't forget to put each array element into single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should precise a little bit more your problem but here is a possibility (to adapt to your case).

I assume that `items` is an array of jQuery elements (so i am calling `.height()`)...

EDIT: your edit shows an array of HTML elements, you can convert it into jQuery elements doing e.g `items = items.map(item => $(item))`

```
let pageInd = 1

// loop over each page
while (items.length) {

  let // stores the items of the current page
      curPageItems = []
  ,   // current page height
      height = 0

  // loop over each elements of the current page
  curPageElmts: while (items.length) {

    // get the next element
    const nextElmt = items.shift()

    // update height
    height += nextElmt.height()

    // break loop if the height goes over 1000px
    if (height > 1000) break curPageElmts

    // otherwise add it to the current page
    curPageItems.push(nextElmt)

  }

  // append those items in the corresponding page
  // (jQuery accepts appending arrays of elements)
  $(`.page-${pageInd++}`).append(curPageItems)

}
```

You can also avoid the last line and store the result in a new Array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try.

Comment: @JavierMolinasVilas i edited my code (which first was wrong sorry) since `.height()` was processed 2 times by item, which is bad

Comment: This works but not as I expected, because the pages have more than 1000px. The second page has 400px and finally, the content changed the position. I need to investigate. Thanks for all!!